# How do people access http-only cookies via javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have found this chrome extension which is able to access and edit http-only cookies. I have done some research and everywhere says that it is not possible to access http-only cookies with javascript. However this is clearly invalid. The chrome extension is called Cookie-Editor.

Here is a screenshot of it having access to an http-only cookie:
[image]

you can see on the bottom right it says it is http-only.

In addition, if you go into console and log the cookies, it does not show up, further proving.

[image]

**How is this done?**

Comment: look at the source https://github.com/Moustachauve/cookie-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser extensions are not subject to the normal restrictions applied to JavaScript loaded via a `<script>` element in a web page.

The [cookies API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/) is available if the extension's manifest grants permission:

> ```
> {
>   "name": "My extension",
>   ...
>   "permissions": [
>     "cookies",
>     "*://*.google.com"
>   ],
>   ...
> }
> ```

(That's for Chrome. Other browsers will have similar systems.)